# RegEx replace for HTML comment newer stop

Tags: c#, .net, regex, filter

I have some file in mht format. On part HTML i do replace on regex.

```
string reta = Regex.Replace(_file, @"\<![ \r\n\t]*(--([^\-]|[\r\n]|-[^\-])*--[ \r\n\t]*)\>",
                            String.Empty, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline |
                            RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

And for something file this replace never stop.
Maybe you can see something wrong in this replace.
I don't add this file because preserve data.

Thanx

PS. I try select out this part.

ANSWER
I changed the query REGEX in the test data set is working.

```
<![ \r\n\t]*--.*?--[ \r\n\t]*>
```

Comment: "something file"? No, sorry, you'll have to provide some source. Make a minimal case, that is, the smallest file that the problem occurs for.

Answer (score 1):

When ever someone posts a question about regex and html I say look at this answer first:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

You need to read it.

Comment: I not parse HTML, I only remove comment from HTML file this operation I do in Regex.